# Python - HTML - to Dict

Tags: python, html

I have a list of params within a .txt file i have saved. This was originally a HTML format - how can i extract the info below as a dict in python?

````
#             'item_size': '40',
#
#             'item_box': 'True',
#
#             'item_papers': 'True',
#
#             'item_special_edition': 'False',
#
#             'item_available': 'instock',```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try to write code to solve the problem? What happened when you tried that code, and how is that different from what you want to happen? Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). This is not a code-writing service; we aren't only interested in what the code needs to do, but specifically why and where you need help in order to write the code.

Comment: You can use regex: `dict(zip(i := iter(re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", text)), i))`

Comment: Please add your expected outcome as well as what you are trying atm and what its returning